# SQL Insert via mappings table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

As part of a SSIS ETL process, I have multiple staging tables.  I have used xxxx just to resemble data:

e.g.

```
tblStage1

    Field_ABC  Field_ZXC  Field_QWE
     xxxx       xxxxxxxxx   xxxxx


tblStage2

Field_PLM   Field_WER   Field_YTE
 xxxxx       xxxxxx      xxxxxxx
```

I then have the 'real' tables that they need to be inserted into:

```
tblDest1
FldABC    FldZXC    FldQWE


tblDest2
FldPLM  FldWER   FldYTE
```

Using info from the Information Schema I have built a mapping table that details which table and field from the staging tables map to which real table:

```
tblMapping:

StageTble   StageColumn   RealTable    RealCol    OrdinalPosition
tblStage1   Field_ABC     tblDest1     FldABC     1
tblStage1   Field_ZXC     tblDest1     FldZXC     2
tblStage1   Field_QWE     tblDest1     FldQWE     3
tblStage2   Field_PLM     tblDest2     FldPLM     1
tblStage2   Field_WER     tblDest2     FldWER     2
tblStage2   Field_YTE     tblDest2     FldYTE     3
```

How do I loop through each staging table and insert into the real tables\columns based on the values in tblMapping?

Would this be possible via a Cursor and a Loop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SSIS works on metadata. ie you need to know schema before inserting. What you're expecting is possible but that's not how anyone would recommend you to use ETL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to automatically archive what you require, aliasing the columns in your source connection to match the destination table columns might just do the trick.

Example for tblStage1 into tblDest1:

```
SELECT Field_ABC AS FldABC, Field_ZXC AS FldZXC, Field_QWE AS FldQWE FROM tblStage1
```

This way, the columns will be mapped automatically by matching names.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.   It's going to take a lot of code though, and I'm not going to write it for you.   But I'll point you in the direction of a solution that can work.

You would create a cursor on a SELECT of DISTINCT `StageTble` in your mapping table.  So in your sample data, the CURSOR would loop through only two rows.

Then for each iteration of the loop (ergo for each Stage Table), you'll generate a dynamic INSERT..SELECT statement for the current Stage Table in the loop.   The statement will look something like this:

```
'INSERT INTO '+@RealTable+' ('+@RealColumns+') 
 SELECT '+@StageColumns+' FROM '@StageTable+';'
```

And before that statement, you'll populate the variables by SELECTING from the mapping table all the rows related to the current Stage Table.  The two "Table" variables are just the Table names, and the two "Columns" variables are comma-separated values generated with a `STUFF..FOR XML` query.   Just be sure to populate the two "columns" variables in the same order.